# How to fix Filter selections on VIEW result pages

Tags: views, paging

1] I am  using Exposed Filters (Page Display - not Block Display) in a view.

2] Sorting by three parameters: Materials, Machines, Industry(s)

3] Using Paging to deliver Results

4] Filters have "Remember last selection" turned off

5] Display>Page>Advanced:
AJAX (OFF - per other threads)
Caching (NONE - per other threads)

6] Drupal 8

Problem: Filter results are fine and not the problem. Filter selections change after initial page. ([Illustrated here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6er29.png))

Regardless of browser - delivers same broken filter selections after page 1.

Help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try to replicate this on a fresh install, if you can replicate it there, then it's clearly a bug. If not, then it's something up with your site. Maybe check browser console for JS errors.

Comment: Thanks No Sssweat. That at least gives me some place to start. I really did not know what to look at, so very much appreciated.

Comment: Also maybe try turning #4 on? I found a few similar issues [Exposed filter selections aren't remembered if query parameters are in the URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1248332) maybe you could try the patch in here. Also, another one ["Remember" feature of exposed filters doesn't work with AJAX and is generally fragile](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2939806)

Comment: I tried your (#4) selection to no avail. I'm going back to an older post backup to see if it exhibits the same behavior. Nothing like forensics! I'm not a programmer, but can at least do my part to narrow down what is going on. But some of the threads I have seen concur with what you are pointing out, mainly that other people have documented the behavior. Crazy thing is that it DID work at one time as expected. But updates have happened since that time. Thanks again No Sssweat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a patch here (see note #5) that worked in my circumstance: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2897694#comment-12677908
Hopefully this can help someone else.